# ActionBarSherlock and ActionBar.OnNavigationListener

Tags: android, android-actionbar, actionbarsherlock

I have ActionBar with list navigation.
As I can see, ActionBar.OnNavigationListener is called only for newly selected positions.
Is there a way to have callback for every selection, even if I select already selected item?

Comment: Do you use tab navigation in the ActionBar? If so, use the `TabListener` interface and its `onTabReselected()` method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I only have a hacky solution to this and I am open for suggestions how to improve it. But it works.

The trick is to have an invisible item that gets selected after the actual selection. This way, `onNavigationItemSelected` gets called again when you reselect the selected item.

```
public class ReselectAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {
    private Context mContext;
    private ArrayList<String> mItems;
    private int mInternalPosition;

    public ReselectAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<String> items) {
        super(context, R.layout.sherlock_spinner_item, items);
        mContext = context;
        mItems = items;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        TextView textView = (TextView) convertView;
        if (textView == null) {
            textView = (TextView) LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(
                    R.layout.sherlock_spinner_item, null);
            textView.setText(mItems.get(mInternalPosition));
        }
        return textView;
    }

    @Override
    public View getDropDownView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup
            parent) {
        TextView textView = null;
        if (position == mItems.size() - 1) {
            textView = new TextView(mContext);
            textView.setHeight(0);
        } else {
            textView = (TextView) LayoutInflater.from(mContext)
                    .inflate(R.layout.sherlock_spinner_dropdown_item, 
                            parent, false);
            textView.setText(mItems.get(position));
        }
        parent.setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(false);
        return textView;
    }

    public void setInternalPosition(int internalPosition) {
        mInternalPosition = internalPosition;
    }
}
```

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // [...]
    ArrayList<String> items = new ArrayList<String>();
    items.add("A");
    items.add("B");
    items.add("C");
    items.add(""); // the last item is the invisible one
    mReselectAdapter = new ReselectAdapter(context, items);
    getSupportActionBar().setListNavigationCallbacks(mReselectAdapter, this);
}
```

```
@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(int itemPosition, long itemId) {
    int navigationItemCount = getSupportActionBar().getNavigationItemCount();
    if (itemPosition == navigationItemCount - 1) {
        return true;
    }
    Log.i("onNavigationItemSelected", mReselectAdapter.getItem(itemPosition));
    mReselectAdapter.setInternalPosition(itemPosition);
    getSupportActionBar().setSelectedNavigationItem(navigationItemCount - 1);
    return true;
}
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, just wondering if you had found a better way?